# Three exponential random variables, given the correlations of two pairs, what is the correlation for the third pair?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let each of random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be exponentially distributed with the same parameter $\lambda>0$. Given two pairs of the correlations
$$\text{corr}(X,Z)=\rho_{XZ}\in (0,1) \text{ and } \text{corr}(Y,Z)=\rho_{YZ}\in (0,1),$$
is it possible to calculate
$$\text{corr}(X,Y)?$$

If they are standard normally distributed, we can proceed by setting
$$X=\rho_{XZ}Z+\sqrt{1-\rho_{XZ}^2}X'$$
and
$$Y=\rho_{YZ}Z+\sqrt{1-\rho_{YZ}^2}Y'$$
where $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z$ are independent and standard normally distributed. Then
$$\text{corr}(X,Y)=\rho_{XZ}\rho_{YZ}.$$
Can we perform a similar analysis for exponential random variables?

Comment: The arguments for the normal distribution part should be based on the assumption that $X, Y, Z$ are jointly multivariate normal. A similar assumption on the dependency structure is also needed for exponential case. It looks like there is not a model of multivariate exponential distribution that is particularly standout from others. Once you make the assumption, you can try to compute.

Comment: Could you elaborate why is the assumption that $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are jointly normal required?

Comment: The relationship you stated above is equivalent to that they are jointly normal. There are multiple (uncountably many) joint distributions makes the random variables satisfy the correlation conditions, but only multivariate normal will make them satisfy the equation you set above.